# New instances not getting added to ECS with EC2 deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am deploying a queue processing ECS service using EC2 deployment using CDK. Here is my stack

```
from aws_cdk import core, aws_ecs_patterns, aws_ec2, aws_ecs


class EcsTestStack(core.Stack):

def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    _container_image = aws_ecs.ContainerImage.from_asset(
        directory=".",
        file='Dockerfile.ECS_Test',
        exclude=["cdk.out"]
    )

    _scaling_steps = [{"upper": 0, "change": -1}, {"lower": 50, "change": +1}, {"lower": 100, "change": +2}]

    _vpc = aws_ec2.Vpc(self, "ecs-test-vpc-v4", max_azs=3)

    _cluster = aws_ecs.Cluster(self, "ecs-test-cluster-v4", vpc=_vpc)

    _cluster.add_capacity("ecs-autoscaling-capacity-v4",
                          instance_type=aws_ec2.InstanceType("t2.small"),
                          min_capacity=1,
                          max_capacity=3)

    self.ecs_test = aws_ecs_patterns.QueueProcessingEc2Service(
        self,
        "ECS_Test_Pattern_v4",
        cluster=_cluster,
        cpu=512,
        scaling_steps=_scaling_steps,
        memory_limit_mib=256,
        image=_container_image,
        min_scaling_capacity=1,
        max_scaling_capacity=5,
    )
```

The stack starts out with 1 task in the service and 1 EC2 instance. Based on my `_scaling_steps`, a new task should be added to the service when the number of messages in the queue > 50 and 2 new tasks should be added to the service. The stack starts out with 1 task in the service and 1 EC2 instance.

But when I add 200 new messages to the queue, I can see 1 new task added to my service and then I get this error message in the even.

> service
> EcsTestStackV4-ECSTestPatternv4QueueProcessingService5C84D200-c00N6R56hB0p
> was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of
> its requirements. The closest matching container-instance
> 81e5380c718c4b558567dc6cc1fb1926 has insufficient CPU units available.

I also notice that no new EC2 instances were added.

Question: how do I get more EC2 instances added to my cluster when the service scales up?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why your issue happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can see 1 new task added to my service and then I get this error message in the even.

This is because t2.small has 1000 CPU units. So your two tasks take all of them, and there is no other instances to place your extra task on.

> I also notice that no new EC2 instances were added.

You set `min_capacity=1` so you have only instance. The `_scaling_steps` are for the tasks only, not for your instances in autoscaling group. If you want more instance you have to set `min_capacity=2` or whatever value you want.

I guess you thought that `QueueProcessingEc2Service` scales both instances and tasks. Sadly this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, that explains it. How do I get the EC2 instances to auto-scale with the tasks?

Comment: @DrkStr No problem. You need to setup [Auto Scaling group capacity provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/asg-capacity-providers.html). But I don't know how to do it in CDK.

Comment: Yup, figured out how to auto-scale capacity providers. Can you add this link to your answer to people coming to this in the future can find it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecs-readme.html#auto-scaling-group-capacity-providers